# How can I accsses class members in static function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1{
    public:
        class1();
        int x;
        int y;
        static int func();
};
int class1::func(){
    return x;
}
int main() {
    class1 c1;
    c1.x=5;
    cout<<c1.func()<<endl;
}
```

When I tried compile this I got an error. How can I accsses x in static function?

Error in terminal:

```
In static member function ‘static int class1::func()’:
    error: invalid use of member ‘class1::x’ in static member function
         return x;
                ^
    note: declared here
             int x;
                 ^
```

Comment: Please paste the error message as well.

Comment: @cigien I added the error message.

Comment: You can't. A `static` function is not called on any objec, so what data should it return?

Comment: A static member function does not have an implicit ‘this’ pointer, so you cannot access non-static class members. The function can access static members, and is often used for methods that are logically related to a class, but don’t use member data: eg a Date class might have a static member function Date::Today() to generate an instance of the class with today’s date.

Answer (score 1):

To access a non-static data member inside a static member function, you need to pass an object of that class to the static function. Otherwise, accessing the data member doesn't make any sense since there is no object associated with a static member function.

Here's one way to do that:

```
int class1::func(class1 const & c) {
    return c.x;
}
```

And then you can call the function like this:

```
class1::func(c1);
```

Comment: which kinda makes static useless.

Comment: @Raildex In this particular case, sure. But there could be some static data that the static function uses as well, in addition to the passed in object's data.